# Implementing C# interfaces with nullable reference types in F#

Tags: .net-core, f#, c#-to-f#, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to learn F# by converting an existing .NET Core solution in C# over, one project at a time. I currently have an interface in C# with nullable reference types:

```cs
public interface IVehicle {
    public int GetWheels();
    public string? GetLicensePlate();
}
```

And this interface is implemented in a number of other projects which depend on this one. I'm trying to convert one of these over, but if I try

```fs
type Car(serialNumber: string) =
    interface MyProjectInterfaces.IVehicle with
        member this.GetWheels() = 4
        member this.GetLicensePlate() = 
            match LicensePlateService.GetLicencePlate(serialNumber) with
                | Some(x) -> System.Nullable(x)
                | None -> System.Nullable()
```

I get the error:

> This expression was expected to have type 'string' but here has type 'Nullable<string>'

This doesn't seem to affect value types, so I'm assuming it's something to do with `string` being a reference type.

What do I do to solve this? Presumably I could rewrite the underlying interface to use F# and thus options, but there are other C# projects that implement the interface and I don't want to have to rewrite the whole solution in one go. Or am I doing F# completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a confusion between C# 8's nullable references and nullable value types, aka `Nullable<T>`. If you look at the definition of `Nullable<T>`, you'll find:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

which means it's only for value types. `int?` is short for `Nullable<int>`.
That's different from nullable *references*.

> The nullability modifier for reference types doesn’t introduce a new type. Reference types are still nullable and compiling `string?` results in IL that’s still just `System.String`.
>
> The difference at the IL level is the decoration of nullable modified types with a `NullableAttribute`.

In other words, it's just a compiler construct - one which isn't visible to F#.

```
match LicensePlateService.GetLicencePlate(serialNumber) with
| Some(x) -> x
| None -> null
```

will be the correct, albeit non-idiomatic replacement.